# Every factor of product topology $X$, is homeomorphic to a retract of $X$.

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

How can I prove this theorem?

> Let $X$ is the topological product of some family $\mathcal A$ of spaces, then every factor is homeomorphic to a retract of $X$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{A}=\{X_i:i\in I\}$ for some index set $I$. Fix a point $p=\langle p(i):i\in I\rangle\in X$. Fix $i_0\in I$, and let $I_0=I\setminus\{i_0\}$. Let

$$Y=\left\{x\in X:\forall i\in I_0\big(x(i)=p(i)\big)\right\}\;.$$

1. Show that $Y$ is homeomorphic to $X_{i_0}$. HINT: Consider the projection $\pi_i:X\to X_i$.
2. Show that $Y$ is a retract of $X$. HINT: There’s a map from $X$ to $Y$ that’s very much like the projection.

In visualizing all of this it may help to consider that if $I=\{0,1\}$ and $X_0=X_1=\Bbb R$, the point $p$ could be $\langle 2,3\rangle$, and if $i_0=1$, then $Y=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:y=3\}$, the graph of the equation $y=3$. The projection $\langle x,3\rangle\mapsto x$ is pretty clearly a homeomorphism. What’s an equally simple retraction of $\Bbb R^2$ onto $Y$? It should send $\langle x,y\rangle$ to ... what?

Comment: 1. $\varphi:Y\to X_{i_0}$ where $\varphi(y)\mapsto x(i_0)$.  2.$f:X\to Y$ where $f(\left\langle {x(i)} \right\rangle ) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
p(i)\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}&{\forall i \in {I_0}}
\end{array}\\
x({i_0})
\end{array} \right$   3. send $\langle x,y\rangle$ to $\langle x,3\rangle$ ??

Comment: @George: (1) is the desired homeomorphism, though of course you have to verify **is** a homeomorphism. (3) is indeed what I had in mind. I **think** that you have the right idea for (2), but I had a hard time reading it. I’d say simply that $f(x)$ is the point $y$ defined by $y(i_0)=x(i_0)$ and $y(i)=p(i)$ for $i\in I_0$; is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes.
Thank you for dedicating time to this question.

Comment: @George: You’re welcome.

Comment: $\varphi$ is 1-1 and continuous (The restriction of a continuous function is continuous, $\pi_{i_0}\vert_Y=\varphi$) and open $\big($In a similar way that we show that $\pi_{i_0}$ is open ( every point is an interior point) $\big)$, but I'm having trouble proving that $f$ is a continuous mapping, I must use the definition to prove or some theorems?‎‎

Comment: @George: $f=\left(\pi_{i_0}\upharpoonright Y\right)^{-1}\circ\pi_{i_0}=\varphi^{-1}\circ\pi_{i_0}$.